# Appcelerator 5.1.1.GA Marshmallow Phone App crashes on start

Tags: titanium, android-6.0-marshmallow, titanium-modules, appcelerator-titanium

When I compile my application targeting android sdk 23 on with 5.1.1.GA and a phone running Marshmallow I get a crash on the startup of the app right after

```
[INFO]  App successfully installed
[INFO]  Starting app: com.rexel.rexelmobile/.RexelUsaActivity
[DEBUG] Trying to start the app...
[INFO]  Application pid: 30040
[INFO]  Project built successfully in 1m 11s 341ms
```

I have no way of knowing what is causing this, if I use a Lollipop phone everything works fine. My log level is the lowest possible.

UPDATE: It is a module. I am working on modifying it to add the ask for permissions requirement. I hope Appcelerator knows that Marshmallow likely broke a majority of the current modules.

Comment: If you are using modules, you can remove them all and try loading them one at a time to confirm that it is not happening due to them

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error as you but I am using 5.1.0.GA.

If you are using any modules, make sure they are updated. I am using ti.imagefactory and had to update it from 2.1 to 2.2 in order to get Android M to actually open my app. Hope this solves your problem.